# 3D calculate new location of point after rotation around origin

Tags: 3d, rotations

I've tried to boil down my problem as much as possible. I've got two questions, but really I'd be satisfied enough just knowing how to accomplish the first one.
I'm looking to do this programatically, so formulas are appreciated.

PointA is located at (x, y, z) in 3d space
The whole world rotates at the origin(0, 0, 0) using (pitch, yaw, roll)
Where is PointA now?

Optional Curiosity:
If an object at PointA has an orientation of (pitch2, yaw2, roll2), what is its new orientation after the world rotation above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply your $<x, y, z>$ vector by a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.28_z-y.E2.80.99-x.E2.80.B3_intrinsic.29_.E2.86.92_Rotation_matrix) to obtain the new position.  For rotation about the $x$ axis by angle $\phi$, followed by rotation about $y$ by $\theta$, then by rotation about $z$ by $\psi$, the rotation matrix would be:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
 \mathbf{A} &=& \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta \cos\psi & \cos\phi \sin\psi + \sin\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi &   \sin\phi \sin\psi - \cos\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi \\
  -\cos\theta \sin\psi &  \cos\phi \cos\psi - \sin\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi & \sin\phi \cos\psi + \cos\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi \\
  \sin\theta             &  -\sin\phi \cos\theta                                          &   \cos\phi \cos\theta \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
$$

Note that the order in which the transformations are applied is significant.  (Matrix multiplication is not commutative.)

Comment: possibly of interest: including  a stretching factor into the calculations